# Probability that a company is worth $xM after y years, if its value can only stay the same or double every year?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let's say a company is worth \$1M. Each year, the value of the company eithers stays the same with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, or doubles with probability $\frac{1}{2}$.

1. What is the probability that the company is worth exactly \$4M after 10 years?
2. What is the general formula for the probability that the company is worth exactly \$$x$M after $y$ years?

For (1), I've come up with $\frac{{10 \choose 2}}{2^{10}}$, since there can only be two years in which the company doubles in value.

However, I'm having a little trouble with (2). Using the logic above, would it simply be $\frac{y \choose \log_2(x)}{2^y}$? Or am I completely off track?

Comment: you are on the right track...

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is a [Binomial Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with $p=\frac{1}{2}$, $n=y$ and $k=x-1$.